# SQL Server - Backup server through

Tags: sql-server, backup, procedure, hard-drive

Is there a way to backup the SQL Server to an external hard drive daily (automatically) through a procedure (query)? I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: If that external harddrive is connected to the machine where SQL Server runs, and doesn't have any restrictive permissions settings (preventing a "normal" user from writing to it) - **sure!** Why not??

Comment: @kevin; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a full SQL Server backup to disk :**

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks 
TO DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK'
GO
```

[SQL Server BACKUP DATABASE command](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/20/sql-server-backup-database-command/)

**As @marc_s said, SQL Server should have write permission on destination address.**